# How to stop whole javascript code containing nested loops and if else statements?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, break

I am a beginner in javascript. I wrote my first program which writes dates in a specific format, i.e., "DOB=mm%2Fdd%2Fyyyy" and gives the output in console.

```
var testdate = "DOB=06%2F07%2F2004"
var minyear = 2003;
for(var year = 2005; year>=minyear; year--){
    if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 == 0){        
        var maxmonth = 12;
        for (var month = 1; month <= maxmonth; month++) {
            var fmonth = ("0" + month).slice(-2);
            if (fmonth == 01 || fmonth == 03 || fmonth == 05 || fmonth == 07 || fmonth == 08 || fmonth == 10 || fmonth == 12) {
                var maxdate = 31;
                for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
                    var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
                    var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F"+ fdate + "%2F" + year
                    console.log(sentdate)
                }
            }
            else if (fmonth == 02) {
                var maxdate = 29;
                for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
                    var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
                    var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F"+ fdate + "%2F" + year
                    console.log(sentdate)
                }
            }
            else {
                var maxdate = 30;
                for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
                    var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
                    var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F"+ fdate + "%2F" + year
                    console.log(sentdate)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        var maxmonth = 12;
        for (var month = 1; month <= maxmonth; month++) {
            var fmonth = ("0" + month).slice(-2);
            if (fmonth == 01 || fmonth == 03 || fmonth == 05 || fmonth == 07 || fmonth == 08 || fmonth == 10 || fmonth == 12) {
                var maxdate = 31;
                for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
                    var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
                    var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F"+ fdate + "%2F" + year
                    console.log(sentdate)
                }
            }
            else if (fmonth == 02) {
                var maxdate = 28;
                for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
                    var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
                    var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F"+ fdate + "%2F" + year
                    console.log(sentdate)
                }
            }
            else {
                var maxdate = 30;
                for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
                    var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
                    var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F"+ fdate + "%2F" + year
                    console.log(sentdate)
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

*I want that whenvever **sentdate** becomes equal to **testdate**, this program will stop at that point. Means, this code shouldn't execute further. I couldn't find any way to do so. Anyone, please help me to achieve this.*

Comment: put the code in a function and `return` when the condition is met

Comment: What is the actual purpose of the code? Notice, that the conditions checking `fmonth`  are rarely passing, `("0" + month).slice(-2);` returns a string, and that string is not even loosely equal to octal numbers until the operand to compare to contains two digits.

Comment: Why don't you use `break`?

Comment: Hmm ... it looks like I was wrong, `01 == '01'` returns `true`, and 08 and 09 works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things happened here.

1. I removed the separate leap year section and just made the # of day in Feb change accordingly
2. I used a separate function to test the `testdate` - why a separate function? b/c otherwise we'd be coding the same logic 3 times
3. To break out of this nested loop, I applied a **loop label** `dateloop:` at the beginning. Then when the match was found, we just break out: `break dateloop;`

```js
var testdate = "DOB=06%2F07%2F2004"

function matchesTestDate(date) {
  return testdate == date;
}
var minyear = 2003;
dateloop: // this is the label for your loop
  for (var year = 2005; year >= minyear; year--) {
    var maxmonth = 12;
    for (var month = 1; month <= maxmonth; month++) {
      var fmonth = ("0" + month).slice(-2);
      if (fmonth == 01 || fmonth == 03 || fmonth == 05 || fmonth == 07 || fmonth == 08 || fmonth == 10 || fmonth == 12) {
        var maxdate = 31;
        for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
          var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
          var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F" + fdate + "%2F" + year
          console.log(sentdate)
          if (matchesTestDate(sentdate)) break dateloop;
        }
      } else if (fmonth == 02) {
        var maxdate = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 == 0) ? 29 : 28;
        for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
          var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
          var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F" + fdate + "%2F" + year
          console.log(sentdate)
          if (matchesTestDate(sentdate)) break dateloop;
        }
      } else {
        var maxdate = 30;
        for (var date = 1; date <= maxdate; date++) {
          var fdate = ("0" + date).slice(-2);
          var sentdate = "DOB=" + fmonth + "%2F" + fdate + "%2F" + year
          console.log(sentdate)
          if (matchesTestDate(sentdate)) break dateloop;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```